# iOS in-app purchase add few downloads in one transaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect, in-app

I'm developing the app where user can download content by tapping related button. I decided to use in-app purchases to host content with Apple servers.

The problem is that after user request an download - StoreKit shows a bunch of pop-ups with confirmations about purchase (those are free). So if user will request few downloads - he has got a lot of popups.

So Is there some different solution for my use case? For example is there possibility to group few products in one transaction? Or is there possibility to suppress system pop-ups about purchases?

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible base on Apple rule , but SKPayment can accept quantity greater than 1.

```
SKMutablePayment *myPayment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct: myProduct];

myPayment.quantity = 2;
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:myPayment];
```

Comment: Seems quantity in this case means to obtain 2 copies of the same product. And Apple just bill twice for single transaction. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, single transaction for 2 same product